Covered strangle vs separate CC+CSP
How does a covered strangle compare to doing a separate covered call (CC) and a cash secured put (CSP)? Which strategy provides a better premium in the long run?
Some folks suggest that one should do a CC when the underlying asset is up and sell a CSP when it is down. While this might provide more premium than a covered strangle, it means more work and requires favorable conditions, otherwise one of the two legs may not materialize before expiration.
In addition, I see that covered call takes more time to get filled as both the CC and CSP have to be satisfied simultaneously. However, it might provide the confidence that the bid price is appropriately chosen.

If you are utilizing the same options and comparing the implementation of both strategies at the same time then there is no difference between the coverage strangle versus a separate covered call and cash a secured put.
If you are trying to sell the covered call on an up day and sell the cash secured put on a down day, the you are attempting to time the market and the result will be different - better if you succeed and worse if not.
If you are trading at the market, as long as there is sufficient liquidity, both trades will be executed at the same time.
If a covered strangle is placed as a single combo order, it has the advantage of no leg in risk and the possibility of lower fees.  It also has the advantage of a better fill price if placed as a limit order.
